# Is this the correct usage of the count function or am I missing something?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, counting

I'm interested in working with two variables from a survey. This is how they appear with the rest of the dataset removed:

| p70506 | p70508 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 4 entirely disagree | 4 entirely disagree |
| 2 0 not applicable | 0 not applicable |
| 4 2 partially agree | 3 entirely disagree |
| 7 1 entirely agree | 3 partially disagree |

What I want is to count the total number of people that partially agrees and entirely agrees with both of those questions. For that, I tried the following:

`dataset %>% filter(p70506 %in% c(1, 2), p70508 %in% c(1, 2)) %>% group_by(p70506, p70508) %>% count(p70506, p70508)`

Which, in turn, gave me the result:

| p70506 | p70508 | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 1 entirely agree | 1 entirely agree | 209 |
| 2 1 entirely agree | 2 entirely agree | 135 |
| 4 2 partially agree | 1 partially agree | 103 |
| 7 2 partially agree | 2 partially agree | 457 |

It seems that the count function returns a matrix counting the repetition of possible combinations between values. But what I am expecting is somewhat diferent:

|  | p70506 | p70508 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Entirely agree | Number | Number |
| Partially agree | Number | Number |
| Total | Number | Number |

Is is possible to do this using count or am I trying to achieve this the wrong way?

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible piece of your data with `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: It's longer than SO would let me post in a comment. Is there anything in particular in the output I can send you?

Comment: yes you can share the `head` of your data as specified in `dput(head(data))` .

Comment: Here's the complete output of the function: [link](https://pastebin.com/fWQMcNG6) and only the columns I'm using: [link](https://pastebin.com/608795qz). Also, the link for the dataset [link](ftp://ftp.datasus.gov.br/dissemin/publicos/SIM/CID10/DOFET/DOEXT19.dbc)

Comment: unfortunately I can't seem to produce your data. Only the selected columns would suffice if you put the output of `dput`  there.

Comment: p70506 = structure(c(4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0), label = "P70506 - (Tenho vergonha de minha renda) Agora vou ler algumas frases sobre sua renda e para cada uma gostaria de saber se você concorda ou discorda dela:", format.spss = "F1.0", labels = c(`Não se aplica` = 0, 
        `Concorda totalmente` = 1, `Concorda em parte` = 2, `Discorda em parte` = 3, 
        `Discorda totalmente` = 4, `Não tem renda no momento` = 6, 
        `Não opinou` = 7), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
        "double")),

Comment: p70508 = structure(c(4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0), label = "P70508 - (Tenho orgulho de minha renda) Agora vou ler algumas frases sobre sua renda e para cada uma gostaria de saber se você concorda ou discorda dela:", format.spss = "F1.0", labels = c(`Não se aplica` = 0, 
        `Concorda totalmente` = 1, `Concorda em parte` = 2, `Discorda em parte` = 3, 
        `Discorda totalmente` = 4, `Não tem renda no momento` = 6, 
        `Não opinou` = 7), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
        "double")),

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `table()` function instead of `count()`. By the way, if you like the tidyverse style, skip `group_by()` and try `pivot_wider()` after the counting is done.

Comment: After using table, I get this output: [link](https://pastebin.com/EdvR8TQN). Can you advice me how to use pivot_wider on it?